# Terraform google_container_cluster adjust maximum retry budget

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I keep getting "Retry budget exhausted (80 attempts)", which takes about 10 minutes. Is there a way to reduce the maximum retry budget so I can iterate my configurations faster?

Using https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google/7.3.0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately **maximum retry budget** is not adjustable at the moment. You can take a look at the closely related [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150436368) registered on **Google's issue tracker**.

If you're interested in this functionality I would encourage you to file a new **feature request**. You can use for that [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187180&template=1162742) link.