# Can I set the "Retry budget" for gcloud beta container clusters create command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I ran this command:

```
gcloud --project=xxx beta container clusters create xxx --network xxx --subnetwork xxx --cluster-secondary-range-name=xxx
```

Turns out I had a typo. My secondary range is actually zzz not xxx. So, I have to wait 30 minutes for my cluster creation to fail and finally see what the actual error is:

> Retry budget exhausted (80 attempts): Secondary range "xxx" does not
> exist in network "xxx", subnetwork "xxx".

That's bad. Until the 30 or so minutes elapses I get no error messages or logs and I can't even delete the cluster until it "finishes" and fails.

There has to be a better way! Can I get this to fail fast or at least get some kind of verbose output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question from the title:

> Can I set the “Retry budget” for gcloud beta container clusters create command?

Currently there is no possibility to change the Retry budget and it also means that `$ gcloud container clusters` command isn't supporting that change either.

You can follow a Feature Request for it, that was created on Issuetracker:

- *[Issuetracker.google.com: Allow configuration of GKE "maximum retry budget" when using custom ranges](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152060505)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Terraform Google container cluster adjust maximum retry budget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60769659/terraform-google-container-cluster-adjust-maximum-retry-budget)*